# Throw exception or treat exception?

Tags: java, methods, exception

What should I do if there is a method that receives null or unexpected values:

- Convert the values to a normal value (treat exception)
  or
- Throw an exception because the values are invalid?

Comment: _"In your opinion"_ . That's just _asking_ for close votes. Maybe reformat the question leaving that out. It doesn't look like it has to be an opinionated question.

Comment: If you have to ask, you should throw the exception. Having to ask means you don't know the right thing to do in the context of your method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends on your use case.

If you want the user of your API to handle nullity, because your API does not specify how the nullity should be handled, throw the exception.

You may alternatively check for null and then throw an IllegalArgumentException with a message explaining why null is not allowed, or what might be possible values.

However, if you want to handle the null value in the implementation, then you must clearly document how the method handles a null condition.

For example, look at how [StringUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html) or [EnumUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/EnumUtils.html#getEnum%28java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.String%29) in [Apache commons-lang](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/index.html) handle nullity.

Another interesting read on exception handling is [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp05254/).

Possible use cases:

Checking for null and default to a default value: This should be documented in the specification of the method.

> ```
> if(value == null) {
>     value = DEFAULT_VALUE;
> }
> ```

This is preferred when the API needs to impose a default behavior. The downside is, the default behavior cannot easily be altered by the user of the API.

Checking for null and throwing a Checked Exception primarily to force the user of the API to handle the null situation:

> ```
> if(value == null) {
>     throw new MyCheckedException("Value cannot be null");
> }
> ```

The user of the API needs to handle it or re-throw it:

```
try {
    MyObject value = doWork();
} catch (MyCheckedException e) {
    handleException(e);
}
```

This method allows the user of the API to have greater control on the exception handling.

The above two methods are safe.

But however, if you want the system to fail only at runtime when a null value is encountered and not force the user of the API to handle the exception, it might be useful to wrap it with a Runtime Exception.

Checking for null and throwing a Runtime Exception:

> ```
> if(value == null)
>     throw new MyRuntimeException("Value is null");
> ```

Under no circumstances would you leave the null condition unchecked.

Answer (score 2):

This highly depends on your context.  I can only comment that the JDK APIs too often opt for throwing an exception, which forces boilerplate checks being added before the method calls. What that especially hurts is *composability* of methods, where you want a `null` value to seamlessly propagate through the chained calls, and only be detected in the end, as opposed to painstakingly checked for at each particular step, requiring a lot of overhead in the way of local variables to hold interim results, if-branching, and so on.

So take the above as some criteria to guide your choice.

Answer (score 1):

If its a situation for only developers should know its a bug.

```
    assert value != null;
```

If its a situation a value never have to be null.

```
    if (value == null) throw new NullPointerException();
```

If its a situation a value realy should not be null.

```
    if (value == null) LOGGER.error("Null value!", new NullPointerException());
```

If its a situation a value likely should not be null.

```
    if (value == null) LOGGER.warn("Null value.");
```

If its a situation a value unusually be null.

```
    if (value == null) LOGGER.info('Value is null.');
```

Any other cases:

Its a design issue, can you overload the method from  `void foo(Object maynull)` to `void foo()`? Maybe a field in a class that often can be null, redesign it to a Object- and a Wrapper-class.

In example (assuming you have no lazy-getters):

```
public class Car{
    Passengers[] p; // Bad idea
    Passengers[] p=new Passengers[0]; // Good idea

    List<Passengers> p; // Bad idea
    List<Passengers> p=new ArrayList<>(); // Good idea
}
```

Or this Example:

```
// Bad idea
public class Tree{
    Bird motacillaFlava=null;
    ...
}

// Good idea
public class Tree{...}
public class BirdInTree{Tree t; Bird motacillaFlava;}
```

Regards.

**Note**: Assert works only with `-ea` flag